# Existe binding de dados no Python

Tags: python, binding

Olá, Galera. Vocês conhecem algum tipo de binding de dados no Python que comumente tem em frameworks em Java, tais como JSF, Spring e etc. Pois já usei o Flask e o Django e não vi um recurso parecido em ambos, dessa forma tenho que setar atributo a atributo em minhas classes. Eu não sei se realmente isso é comum no mundo Python, pois se não for, então fui muito mal acostumado no Java rsrs...
Desde já agradeço.

Seria uma forma automática de setar os atributos em uma classe, por exemplo:

```
class Endereco(object):
  logradouro = None
  numero = None
class Pessoa(object):
  nome = None
  idade = None
  endereco = Endereco

params = { "nome": "Lol", "idade": 30, "endereco": { "logradouro": "rua longe pra cacete", "numero": "300" } }

p = binding(params, Pessoa) // método mágico que cria um o objeto do tipo Pessoa a partir do mapa
```

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor o que seria esse *binding de dados* que deseja?

Comment: pronto! parceiro atualizei o post para explicar melhor a minha dúvida

Comment: Acredito que não há nada desse tipo, até porque Python não é fortemente tipado, como o Java. Tem como fazer uma função que faça isso, mas acredito que manualmente é mais indicado. [Aqui](https://repl.it/H3Fu/0) tem um código que fiz bem superficial que faz o que quer, mas reafirmo, fiz bem superficialmente apenas para teste. Quem sabe pode se basear nele e fazer algo interessante.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito obrigado pela sua gentileza de escrever um exemplo, ele já vai servir de grande ajuda para mim

Answer (score 0):

Não existe na biblioteca padrão - mas é algo relativamente fácil de fazer colocando o código pra isso na sua classe de base - e chamando o construtor dessa classe.

Infelizmente isso deixa muitas formas de se fazer isso - nesse exato momento, na lista de e-mais `python-ideas` [está se debatendo uma possível inclusao de uma forma padronizada de se fazer isso](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2017-April/045460.html) (depois de acessar o link, clique em `thread` no final da página para ver todos os e-mais) - nessa discussão, u sou favorável a um decorator - e de forma alguma a uma nova sintaxe, como o autor original da thread sugere.

Mas uma classe base é ainda mais simples que um decorator - Então - Python permite que uma função receba qualquer quantidade de parãmetros com nome, sem saber seus nomes de antemão - basta prefixar um parâmetro com `**` na assiantura da função que os vários parâmetros são empactotados como um dicionário.
De forma análoga, na chamada de uma função, prefixar um objeto do tipo  `mapping` (como um dicionário) com `**` desempacota todos os items do dicionário como parâmetros para uma função.

Isso permite que tenhamos no método `__init__` da classe base um código que receba todos os parâmetros, verifique se o atributo existe na classe, e, se existir, faça o binding do mesmo. De brinde, você pode ate'implementar type-checking, verificando se um parâmetro é uma sub-classe do parâmetro declarado na classe:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        cls = self.__class__
        # itera em uma cópia dos items do dicionário, 
        # permitindo que ele seja alterado durante o "for":
        for name, value in list(kwargs.items()):
            # Verifica se o parâmetro existe na própria classe,
            # caso contrário, mantem o mesmo no dicionário.
            if not hasattr(cls, name):
                continue
            if not isinstance(value, getattr(cls, name)):
                raise TypeError("Incorrect parameter type passed for {}. An '{}' was expected.".format(
                    cls.__name__, getattr(cls, name).__name__))
            setattr(self, name, value)
            del kwargs[name]


class Pessoa(Base):
    nome = str
    idade = int
    endereco = dict
```

E, no modo interativo:

```
In [104]: params = { "nome": "Lol", "idade": 30, "endereco": { "logradouro": "rua longe pra cacete", "numero": "300" } }
     ...: 

In [105]: p  = Pessoa(**params)

In [106]: p.nome, p.idade, p.endereco
Out[106]: ('Lol', 30, {'logradouro': 'rua longe pra cacete', 'numero': '300'})

In [107]: params["idade"] = "muito velho"

In [108]: p2 = Pessoa(**params)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)
TypeError: Incorrect parameter type passed for Pessoa. An 'int' was expected.
```

Comment: Nesse caso, os atributos definidos seriam atributos de classe. Para mantê-los como atributos de instância seria necessário definí-los dentro do inicializador e chamar o inicializador da classe `Base` manualmente (tipo [isso](https://ideone.com/3GxU2X))?

Comment: SIm - c o inicializador da classe Base usa os atributos de classe como guias para saber quais atributos de instancia criar e quais seus tipos. Mas note que se você não precisa deum inicializador específico nas classes derivadas, não precisa chamar o inicializador da Base - ele será chamado automaticamente.